# Interface orientation issue in ipad ios 5.1

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have created a universal application for iPhone and iPad. In this application, the iPhone is `navigation` type and the iPad is `tab bar` type. The iPhone supports both landscape and portrait orientation, the iPad application supports only landscape.

In the iPad I am displaying the `TabBarController` after the login window (present model view), when I run the iPad application first time it always run in the portrait mode. Even if I set the orientation mode to landscape and also should auto rotate for landscape.

So please can any one suggest me where I am wrong or how I forcefully display the view in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forcefully changed the orientation using below code. and its works fine for me:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector (setOrientation:)]) {
  SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString (@" setOrientation:");
  NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[UIDevice instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
  [invocation setSelector:selector];
  [invocation setTarget:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
  int Val = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
  [invocation setArgument:& val atIndex:2];
  [invocation invoke];
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this safe with review guidelines? This is private API

Comment: Still, it's a private API that might as well disappear one day. It's better to apply appropriate `CGAffineTransform` to view and subviews and change status bar orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code in your applicationdelegate.m file

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

and also remove [self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];

this will definitely working..
```

Comment: already doing this. in case of ipad: self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
and iphone self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

Comment: application is universal. navigationcontroller in iphone and tabbarcontroller in ipad. and its not orientation issue is not solved after the above thing in ipad.